# Cómo pasar un conjunto de bytes[] a int en java?

Tags: java, byte

Estoy haciendo un pequeño proyecto escolar en el que tengo que enviar un paquete por un canal y recibir una confirmación (ACK). Estoy recibiendo un `Bytebuffer buffer` que tiene la información que quiero entre los bytes 6 y 9 (4 bytes en total), en ella se almacena un número de secuencia. Es posible que en la secuencia haya un `0x00 0x00 0x00 0x11` como un `0x11 0x10 0x00 0x01` con lo que no me sirve coger únicamente el último byte.

Se os ocurre alguna manera de coger esos 4 bytes y pasarlos a un entero?

`0x00 0x00 0x00 0x11` -> 17

`0x11 0x10 0x00 0x01` -> 286261249

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar [ByteBuffer.wrap](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bytebuffer-wrap-method-in-java-with-examples/)

El método wrap () de la clase java.nio.ByteBuffer se usa para envolver una matriz de bytes en un búfer. El nuevo búfer estará respaldado por la matriz de bytes dada; es decir, las modificaciones al búfer harán que la matriz se modifique y viceversa. La capacidad y el límite del nuevo búfer serán array.length, su posición será cero y su marca será indefinida. Su matriz de respaldo será la matriz dada y su desplazamiento de matriz será cero.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        byte[] bytes = new byte[]{0x11,0x10,0x00,0x01};
        
        int result = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes).getInt();
        
        System.out.println("result: " + result);
        
        
        byte[] bytes2 = new byte[]{0x00,0x00, 0x00,0x11};
        
        int result2 = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes2).getInt();
        
        System.out.println("result1: " + result2);
    }
```

Otra opcion es usar [BigInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) usando esto:

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[]{0x00,0x00, 0x00,0x11};
    
    
System.out.println("result1: " + new BigInteger(bytes).intValue());
```